# Fetch image inside description tag RSS Reader/Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, rss

I am trying to build a simple RSS reader app, but i cannot fetch the image (img src) which is inside description tag of the rss feed. Do you have any suggestions?

```
         <description><![CDATA[<table><tr><td VALIGN=TOP>
<img src="http://prizma.birn.eu.com/мк/file/show/Images/Текстови/0915/daravel.jpg" width="125" alt="" />       </td><td width=850><font size=2><b>Призма</b> - 12:16 24/03<br>
       Пет години откако Македонија, Хрватска, Црна Гора и Србија потпишаа договори за екстрадиција на сопствените државјани, уапсен е човекот кој важеше за најбогатиот кумановец. Тој свое засолниште во последнава деценија најде во Белград, откако во ...
<br /><b>Капитал</b>: <a href="http://www.time.mk/c/0a0fc87312/pukna-zastitata-na-daravelski.html">Драган Даравелски е уапсен во Србија и тече постапка за негова екстрадиција</a>
<br /><b>МКД</b>: <a href="http://www.time.mk/c/0a0fc87312/pukna-zastitata-na-daravelski.html">Во Србија е уапсен Драган Даравелски, се чека на негова екстрадиција во Македонија</a>
<br /><b>Вест</b>: <a href="http://www.time.mk/c/0a0fc87312/pukna-zastitata-na-daravelski.html">Македоснката полиција потврди дека во Србија е уапсен Драган Даравелски</a>
<br /><strong><a href="http://www.time.mk/c/0a0fc87312/pukna-zastitata-na-daravelski.html">45 поврзани вести &raquo;</a></strong>       </font></td></tr></table>]]></description>
         <category>Македонија</category>
      </item>
```

Here's my method:

```
private void ProcessXml(Document data) {
        if (data != null) {
            feedItems=new ArrayList<>();
            Element root = data.getDocumentElement();
            Node channel = root.getChildNodes().item(1);
            NodeList items = channel.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                Node cureentchild = items.item(i);
                if (cureentchild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    FeedItem item=new FeedItem();
                    NodeList itemchilds = cureentchild.getChildNodes();
                    for (int j = 0; j < itemchilds.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node cureent = itemchilds.item(j);
                        if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                            item.setTitle(cureent.getTextContent());
                        }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
                            item.setDescription(cureent.getTextContent());
                        }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){
                            item.setPubDate(cureent.getTextContent());
                        }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                            item.setLink(cureent.getTextContent());
                        }
//Here i want to process the image from the description tag
                    }
                    feedItems.add(item);                 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For example this rss feed:

Comment: Please be more specific, you're saying "I can't load the image", so what have you already tried?

Comment: I edited my post. There is an example with a description tag. So, the image link is insude <img src. Do you have any ideas how can i get this link?